# How to Async/Await a button click, not just wait on the await the page, but wait an action performed on the page before returning

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to figure out how to perform what is mentioned in the title. I will provide a code sample of what I am trying to achieve below. Neverthless, I need to be able to await a page load AND then await an action on that page of clicking a button BEFORE it moves on to execute the code below the awaiting of the page.

currently if I do something like the code below, it loads page A and then just keeps going to load page B because I don't know how to make it await my action on page A

```html
//do some stuff in here
//then push page "A"
//await page "A" to load
//but also await for button
//"A" to be pressed
await DoStuffThenPushPageA()


//DO NOT EXECUTE DostuffThenPushPageB() until "A" is pressed


//do some stuff in here
//then push page "B"
//await page "B" to load
//but also await for button
//"B" to be pressed
await DostuffThenPushPageB()
```

Comment: why wouldn't just put the dependent code in the click handler of Page B's button?

Comment: You almost never want to use `await` to asynchronously wait for user input. It generally means that the user *can only do one thing*. Use normal events instead, or something like RxUI if you want something more declarative.

Comment: @Jason this is how I had it, However, page B is another instance of page A -  they just are displaying a very very minor change in view. And I was told this was not a good solution but it made sense to me.

Comment: @StephenCleary What is this RxUI?

Comment: Add a parameter to the page to determine which mode it is in

Comment: @Jason not quite seeing your vision here, can you elaborate?

Comment: It would be more useful if you edited your question to more clearly explain what you are doing

Comment: You can use CanExecute() in your command by Button B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an `event` in `PageA` and notify `MainPage` when the action in `PageA` finished, then perform `DostuffThenPushPageB`:

In MainPage:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    goToPage1Async();
}

public async void goToPage1Async()
{

    //DO STUFF
    Console.WriteLine("dostuff and go to Page1");
    Page1 page1 = new Page1();

    page1.myActionFinish += Page1_myActionFinish1;

    await Navigation.PushAsync(page1);
}

private void Page1_myActionFinish1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this method will be executed when doMyStuff in Page1 completed
    // then go to page2
    Console.WriteLine("start to go to Page2");
    Page2 page2 = new Page2();
    //await Navigation.PushAsync(page2);        

}
```

In Page1:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{

    public event EventHandler myActionFinish;
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        doMyStuff();
    }

    private void doMyStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("doMyStuff in Page1");

        //If the stuff has been finsihed, notify MainPage to startPage2
        if (myActionFinish != null)
        {
            myActionFinish(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your click eventhandler on your button asynchronous:

```
private async void ButtonA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   await SomeStuff();
}
```

I guess that you want the user to do things in a given sequence

Comment: This was my solution, I was told this was not a good solution.

Comment: I don't think there is anything particularly wrong with it

Comment: No, there is not. The main UI-thread is not blocked. And you can have several asynchronous event handlers "running" at the same time

Comment: But of cause if the SomeStuff() method in some way is blocking the UI thread, then it is another story